# Pang Gesture Recognizer stop

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uipangesturerecognizer

want to use a `UIView` like a `UIScrollView` for more reason, i create a Action with PanGestureRecognizer that's the simple code:

```
- (IBAction)moveUp:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.containerView];
    recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x, recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];

}
```

But i want to stop dragging when my `containerView` bottom is in exact position, follow the screens:

**This is the full `viewController`, all button you see is inside a `containerView`**

[image]

**This is when i open the application:**

[image]

The header image is in a `ViewController` below and all button you see is inside a `containerView`, now i want to fix this position with absolute y, my `containerView` can't drag down.

Now the function can't stop, when i dragUp this is what happen:

[image]

My `containerView` can drag over the end of the `containerView` and i don't want that is possible, i want block the drag up in the end of `containerView` like this screen:

[image]

And when i drag down again i want to stop drag in starter position (screen 1).

Thanks for any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve sounded fun to me at first glance, so I wanted to give it a try.

I modified your gesture recognizer's call back to the following:

```
- (IBAction)panned:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:yourContainerView];

    CGFloat yWithinBounds = 0.0f;

    if(recognizer.view.center.y + (recognizer.view.bounds.size.height / 2.0f) > yourContainerView.bounds.size.height)
    {
        yWithinBounds = yourContainerView.bounds.size.height - (recognizer.view.bounds.size.height / 2.0f);
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^
        {
            recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x, yWithinBounds);
        }];
    }
    else if(recognizer.view.center.y - (recognizer.view.bounds.size.height / 2.0f) < yourContainerView.bounds.origin.y)
    {
        yWithinBounds = yourContainerView.bounds.origin.y + (recognizer.view.bounds.size.height / 2.0f);
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^
        {
            recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x, yWithinBounds);
        }];
    }
    else
    {
        recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x, recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
        [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f) inView:self.view];
    }
}
```

In the first `if`, we are checking if the current center point of your contained view + half the size of it is going out of bounds of the containing view on the ***bottom***; if it is, instead of simply disallowing it to go further, I took the liberty of putting this in an animation block to animate the contained view back to within the containing view so that it looks a bit better visually.

In the `else-if`, we are doing the same except this time for the top of the containing view - we are checking if the contained view is going out of bounds on ***top***; if it is, we animate it back within the containing view.

If the `else` clause is reached, that would mean the contained view is within the containing view's bounds - here, we simply translate it like you originally do.

Here is how I set up the views as test:

```
yourContainerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
yourContainerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor brownColor];
[self.view addSubview:yourContainerView];

UIView *viewWithinContainer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){{yourContainerView.bounds.origin.x, yourContainerView.bounds.origin.y}, yourContainerView.bounds.size.width, 50.0f}]; 
viewWithinContainer.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
[yourContainerView addSubview:viewWithinContainer];

UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panned:)];
[viewWithinContainer addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
```

Feel free to adjust the `height` (i.e., `50.0f` to other values) of the view (hereby: the `viewWithinContainer`) within the container; the way the code is set up, you would not need to change any other values else where even if you change the `height`.

You could also change the animation duration to your need.

I am moving the thing up and down in my simulator at the moment; looks simple but fun to play around.

---

***Update after question update:***

Your new update seems to differ somewhat greatly from what you originally asked, but here is the solution:

The complexity is direction. There are other ways to find out; but I am using mine here, through which we don't need to create another variable.

If you are using storyboard, please set up an `IBOutlet` for your container view, because we would like to obtain the following values (carry out the following in `initWithFrame` and `initWithCoder`):

```
p1 = viewWithinContainer.center.y;
p2 = viewWithinContainer.center.y - (yourContainerView.bounds.size.height - viewWithinContainer.bounds.size.height);
```

Please set up `p1` and `p2` as ivars:

```
CGFloat p1;
CGFloat p2;
```

Here is the updated method for a contained view ***larger*** than the containing view:

```
- (IBAction)panned:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:yourContainerView];

    if(translation.y < 0)
    {
        if(recognizer.view.center.y + (recognizer.view.bounds.size.height / 2.0f) + translation.y > yourContainerView.bounds.size.height)         {
            recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x, recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
            [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];
        }
        else
        {
            recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x, p2);
            [recognizer setTranslation:translation inView:self.view];
        }
    }
    else if(translation.y > 0)
    {
        if(recognizer.view.center.y - (recognizer.view.bounds.size.height / 2.0f) + translation.y < yourContainerView.bounds.origin.y)
        {
            recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x, recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
            [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];
        }
        else
        {
            recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x, p1);
            [recognizer setTranslation:translation inView:self.view];
        }
    }
}
```

The method will ensure that, as you scroll down, the top of the contained view will stop at the edge of the container on ***top***; and as you scroll up, at the edge of the container on the ***bottom***.

I ran this in the simulator; and japp, it has been fun doing this. Enjoy. :-)

Comment: thanks fro your answer, i try to understand your code, because your animation make me confused, I inprove my question with screen in just 5 minute thanks

Comment: Thanks, i uploaded the images, is a fix UIView in a storyboard.

Comment: thanks fro your very well answer, I do every, working very well from start to top, but when the container view is end can't drag down